# Hibernate Criteria Query to outer join sub-queries results

Tags: hibernate, subquery, criteriaquery

I have a requirement to convert the below SQL query into a criteria query.
There is just one table and note that it is not a case for self join.

```
SELECT atable.c1 AS ac1, btable.c1 as bc1 
  FROM (
       SELECT a.c1 
         FROM table_child a 
        WHERE a.c2='XXX') atable 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT b.c1 
             FROM table_child b 
            WHERE b.c3 ='YYYYY') btable 
       ON atable.c1 = btable.c1
```

I am aware of how to use `DetachedCriteria` using `org.hibernate.criterion.Subqueries` to do things like `IN()`, `NOT EXISTS()`, etc. But the `SubQueries` class seems to be mainly for `WHERE` clause.

How do I use a SubQuery to perform a join as shown in the above SQL query. I need to do this using Hibernate Criteria Query.

Thanks.

Comment: I realize I can do this with a subselect. But can I have a subselect in the projection list in a criteria query? If yes, how? SQL equivalent would something like - select
    person.name,
    (select city.name from T_CITY city where city.code = person.city) as city_name
from
   T_PERSON person